# Wordpress - fatal error wp-widget.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have error on my website: lukas-tv.pl

I've reinstalled wordpress and still the same:

```
Warning: require(/home/keramxd/domains/lukas-tv.pl/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php): failed to open stream: Success in /home/keramxd/domains/lukas-tv.pl/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 217

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/keramxd/domains/lukas-tv.pl/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php71/lib/php/') in /home/keramxd/domains/lukas-tv.pl/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 217
```

Comment: Error is self explaining, your file path is wrong

Comment: Where will I find correct file?

Comment: you posted the same question yesterday, here is the file you are missing https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/master/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php

Comment: @madalinivascu I uploaded this file and still the same...

Comment: where did you upload it?

Comment: that could be a permission issue.

Comment: I uploaded it to:
/domains/lukas-tv.pl/public_html/wp-includes/
and
/home/keramxd/domains/lukas-tv.pl/public_html/

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities :

1. You update your wordpress site and one of your plugins is calling a deprecated file. If so, try to disable all of your plugins. (Obviously here, this file is not deprecated, but it is a general thing to do).
2. The site directories don't have correct permissions. If so, do a `chmod -Rf 755` on the site root.
3. Your installation is corrupted and you should reinstall Wordpress.